# AWS - Errors - Updating Auto Scaling group, Amazon CloudFormation, Failed to deploy configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Within the AWS -> Elastic Beanstalk (Dashboard) -> Configuration -> Software Configuration -> Environment Properties

When I try to add & configure my "Environment Properties" from the config file ".env.default" of my node.js application which is as follows:

```
#.env.default

# General settings
TIMEZONE=Europe/Amsterdam

# --------

# Debug-related settings
LOG_LEVEL_CONSOLE=info
LOG_LEVEL_FILE=info
ENABLE_FILE_LOGGING=true

# Whether the local log directory (./logs/) should be preferred over /var/log/
LOG_FILE_PREFER_LOCAL=false

# Override the default logging location (/var/log/ or ./logs/)
# FORCE_LOG_LOCATION=./some-other-directory/
# /../../log/nodejs/

# --------

# Crash-related settings
MAX_CONSECUTIVE_CRASHES=5
CONSECUTIVE_CRASH_RESET_MS=5000

# --------

# Settings relating to remote API access
ENABLE_REMOTE_ACCESS=true
ENABLE_WHITELIST=true
HOST_API=true
HOST_WEB_INTERFACE=true
LISTEN_PORT=8081
JWT_SECRET=ItsASecretToEverybodyMAHBOI

# LISTEN_PORT=1903 backup
#INTERNAL_LISTEN_PORT=1939 backup

# --------

# Settings relating to internal access
INTERNAL_LISTEN_PORT=8083

# --------

# Database-related settings
DATABASE_HOST=acc-sc-3.crmhqy2lzjw4.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DATABASE_NAME=acc_schedule_center_3
DATABASE_USER=sc_3
DATABASE_PASS=yCFKIqzLcBIBt1wYj4Qn
MAX_IDLE_TIME=28800
```

[Environment Properties - First Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHces.png)

[Environment Properties - Second Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIxhR.png)

Ignore the data that is listed inside the "Property Name" & "Property Value", cause they were from the previous configuration.

The Core Error, I'm facing at the moment is as follows:

**ERROR #1**

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named
>   'awseb-e-4e98c2gukw-stack' aborted operation. Current state:
>   'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: null

**ERROR #2**

> Updating Auto Scaling group named:
>   awseb-e-4e98c2gukw-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1GR8E4SU6QZGJ failed
>   Reason: Template error: DBInstance aa153clv2zourf2 doesn't exist

**ERROR #3**

> Failed to deploy configuration.

I'm fairly new, or can call me a novice coder or DevOps in general, but would like to know if anyone knows the solution for these errors?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Kind Regards,

Doga

Comment: From within Elasticbeanstalk, check the 'Events' for the environment. It may have some better logging than the CloudFormation rollback error. Error 1 & 2 would need the CFT to debug.

Comment: @alphaunlimitedg have you found a way to make it work? I'm having the exact same issue and I'm at a loss. Thanks!

Comment: @alphaunlimitedg I'm curious about this myself. I am having this same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix my problem by adding some IAM policies to the EBS user.

I had only the AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk policy and after I added the AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleRDS policy it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same issue. For me it was the permission level of the IAM user that I was using for EB. It had EB Full permissions, but I needed to give it permissions to access other services as well.